# Creating SharePoint 2013 Workflow Associations with Powershell

Tags: 2013, workflow, workflow-manager

Summary: How do I create SharePoint 2013 Workflow Associations through Powershell? SharePoint 2013 workflows do not show up on the WorkflowTemplates list of the SPWeb.

I am attempting to associate a SharePoint 2013 Workflow to a document library using PowerShell.

The workflow was deployed to a on-premise SharePoint farm using a No Code Sandbox Solution.

If I go through the usual Web Interface the Workflow is visible and, if I follow through the association, functional.

However, if I try to get the list SPWeb.WorkflowTemplates I am shown only the SP2010 style workflow templates.

I'm automating the deployment and want to create the association through PowerShell so that I don't need to write a step by step for a non-sharepoint savvy deployer (to be followed in various environments [they actually have 3 tiers - I love bank clients]).

As it stands, creating the association declaratively as part of the feature deployment works. I am wondering how this could be done if that were not an alternative (also, declarative association creates 3 associations - one for each type of event / don't like that).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because SharePoint 2013 Workflows are hosted on Workflow Manager. So you need to add a new workflow subscription to Workflow Manager. I found the following articular useful to workout how to do this. Although this uses the CSOM rather than PowerShell.

[Working with the SharePoint 2013 Workflow Services Client Side Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn481315.aspx)

Here is a PowerShell examples. To get the workflows installed use the WorkflowDeploymentService:

```
    $web = get-spweb "http://yourWebUrl"    
    $wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($web)
    $defSevice = $wfm.GetWorkflowDeploymentService()
    $wfDefs = $defSevice.EnumerateDefinitions($false)
    $wfDef = $wfDefs | where {$_.Id -eq "ID of the WorkflowDefinition"}
```

Once you have found the id of the WorkflowDefinition you would like to associate to the list you can create a new WorkflowSubscription and publish it to your list using the WorkflowSubscription service:

```
    $wfsubService = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
    $wfTaskList = $web.Lists["Workflow Tasks"];
    $wfHistoryList = $web.Lists["Workflow History"];
    $list = $web.List["List you want to add to"];

    #Create Workflow Subscription 
    $sub = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscription
    $sub.DefinitionId = {this is the id of the WorkflowDefinition}
    $sub.Enabled = $true
    $sub.Name = $wfDef.DisplayName

    #Build start options
    $startOptions = New-Object "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.String]"
    $startOptions.Add("ItemAdded") #When item added
    $startOptions.Add("ItemUpdated") #When item updated
    $startOptions.Add("WorkflowStart") #Allow manual start
    $sub.EventTypes = $startOptions

    $sub.SetProperty("HistoryListId", $wfHistoryList.Id)
    $sub.SetProperty("TaskListId", $wfTaskList.Id)

    $wfSubService.PublishSubscriptionForList($sub, $list.Id);
```