# How to add a OOB Approval workflow to a document library using CSOM?

Tags: workflow, office-365, workflow-manager

Can anyone help me on steps to associate the default approval workflow to a SharePoint Library through CSOM ?

**Update:**
When i call ennumeratedefinitions(true) on the workflowservices manager, it only gives the collection of SP13 Workflows. The 2010 Approval WF is not getting intialize.

Comment: What is the code you have tried?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/122936/creating-sharepoint-2013-workflow-associations-with-powershell?rq=1

Comment: I am following the method mentioned in the link but when i try to ennumeratedefinitions , i do not get a value intialized in my collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add OOTB 2010 workflow to SharePoint List by CSOM .
Get the List of SharePoint 2010 Workflow Templates by using the below method

```
webObj.WorkflowTemplates
```

I needed the Approval workflow. So i get it by its name after finding out in previous method.

```
$wfApprovalWFTemplate = webObj.WorkflowTemplates.GetByName("Approval - SharePoint 2010")
```

Note:

> When getting the list of workflows using the Workflow Service Manager Class will return only all those WF's created by SP2013 . i.e Through Workflow Manager.

Create a Workflow Association info

```
$wfassociationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Workflow.WorkflowAssociationCreationInformation;
$wfassociationInfo.Template = $wfApprovalWFTemplate;
$wfassociationInfo.Name = "Document Approval"
$wfassociationInfo.TaskList ="#Task List to Assign"
$wfassociationInfo.HistoryList = "#WF History List to Assign"
```

Associate to the Document Library where you want the approval WF to be added .

```
Write-Host "Create a new Workflow Associationg with the Neccesary information."
$wf = $listWFToAdd.WorkflowAssociations.Add($wfassociationInfo)
$wf.AutoStartChange = $true
$wf.AutoStartCreate = $true
$wf.AssociationData = $customAssociationData //XML data to store WF Options--You can loop through and get this value from existing workflows to get the structure and settings done.
$wf.Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to set `EnableModeration = true`.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var web = ctx.get_web();
var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle('Your list');
list.set_enableModeration(true);
list.set_enableMinorVersions(true);
list.set_defaultContentApprovalWorkflowId("guid");
list.update()
```

Comment: i want the OOB Approval workflow to be added to the document library.

Comment: Yes this will actually do that.